# Word allows users to create nested controls even during protection enforcement. Workaround?

Tags: microsoft-word, security, microsoft-word-2010

I am trying to create a document with restricted editing in which users will only be allowed to fill in information in rich text controls. I will then programmatically grab the data from each rich text control. The problem is that despite having restricted editing, if users copy and paste text from within a control to the same control, they will paste not just the text, but also a copy of the control, thereby creating a nested control. This is a problem when I want an expected set of controls for my program. Anyone know how to prevent users from being able to create controls during protection enforcement that doesn't involve VBA or macros being on? (I want this document to work in any security environment)

Thank you,

P.S. Oh and here is how to re-create this bug in case you're curious:

In Word 2010:

1. Create a new word document
2. Click on "Developer" tab
3. Click on "Design Mode" icon
4. Click on "Rich Text Control" icon (to the left of the "Design Mode" icon)
5. Click on "Design mode" icon again (to deactivate it)
6. Click on "Restrict Editing" icon
7. In the "2. Editing Resistrictions" section, check the box and select "Filling in forms"
8. In the "3. Start enforcement" section, click on "Yes, Start Enforcing Protection"
9. Don't enter a password, just click OK at the "Start Enforcing Protection" box
10. Type "test" (in the control)
11. Double click the word to select it
12. Copy it (Ctrl-C)
13. Place your cursor (with your mouse is easiest) at the beginning of the control (before the first 't' of "test" will do)
14. Paste the contents of the clipboard (Ctrl-V) as many times as you like
15. You have not only pasted the word 'test', but you have also pasted the control inside of itself. You have now created a new content control in an editing restricted/protection enforced environment.

To confirm you have pasted nested controls:

1. Click on the "Stop Protection" button in the "Restrict Editing" sidebar (If you closed the tab, just click on the "Restrict Editing" icon again in the Developer tab.)
2. Click on the "Design Mode" button in the Developer tab.

Comment: Are you trying to a create a form in Word? What about Adobe Acrobat instead?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately, it has to be Word.

Comment: Can you make the Word doc read-only? Can you also paste as unformatted text always?

Comment: The word document would need to be filled out, saved and returned so it couldn't be read-only. The goal is for the end users filling the form to not need specific work around instructions (such as "please paste as unformatted" or "please don't copy and paste within the controls"). As an aside, I am actually surprised that, from a Google search, I have not seen anyone else ask this question seeing as (for better or worse) a lot of people use Word for forms, and a lot of people copy and paste while entering text.

Comment: What happens when you use Plain Text Content Control instead?

Comment: Can't duplicate the issue in Word 2013.

Comment: Plain text control also has this issue. Thanks for trying it out in Word 2013, but I also tried it in Word 2013 and replicated it: http://i.imgur.com/rFQXPyG.jpg Make sure you also do the confirmation steps. The nested controls aren't obvious until you enter design mode again.

Comment: OK I did more testing with Word 2013 and here are the results: Plain text controls have this issue but not with the simple steps outlined in my post (more tinkering is required and eventually creates nested controls), rich text controls have this issue with the simple steps outlined in my post.

Comment: Are the content controls read by software of yours? If so, would it be possible to just make your program more resilient to this problem?